# Remove one property from object array

Tags: javascript, json

I want to remove one property from object array

```
"[{"name":"vv","age":"12","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","age":"13","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","age":"123","id":"124"}]"
```

i want remove age property from the array my output should be

```
[{"name":"vv","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","id":"124"}]"
```

Answer (score 8):

You can use `array.map`, `destructuring` and `rest`:

```js
var arr = [{"name":"vv","age":"12","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","age":"13","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","age":"123","id":"124"}];

arr = arr.map(({ age, ...rest}) => rest);

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: Very slow and very inefficient for this case because the original array can be modified, thus eliminating the waistful need to create a whole new copy of everything.

Comment: perfect solution

Answer (score 4):

In case you want to update existing array (use [delete](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/delete))

```js
var arr = [{"name":"vv","age":"12","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","age":"13","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","age":"123","id":"124"}];

arr.forEach((item) => delete item.age);

console.log(arr);
```

In case you want to create new array (use [Array.map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map))

```js
var arr = [{"name":"vv","age":"12","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","age":"13","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","age":"123","id":"124"}];

    var arr1 = arr.map(({ age, ...obj}) => obj);
    
    console.log(arr1); // updated
    console.log(arr); // no change
```

Comment: A point of clarification (just in case it's not obvious) - this will mutate the original array and objects contained in it.

Comment: @vlaz - I know that is why I have not reassigned anywhere.

Comment: Oh, I agree with this solution. It's fast, straight forward, and efficient. I just wanted to clarify in case somebody doesn't understand that the exact implications.

Comment: @vlaz - I have updated my answer to elaborate both cases. Hope it clarifies now.

Comment: Unfortunately, I cannot give you more than one upvote :)

Answer (score 2):

```
var arr='[{"name":"vv","age":"12","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","age":"13","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","age":"123","id":"124"}]';

var JSON_ARRAY= JSON.parse(arr);

JSON_ARRAY.forEach( function (arrayItem)
 {
     delete arrayItem.age;
 });
```

Comment: @veeresh i try this answer

Comment: Why use jQuery instead of the native `JSON.parse()`?

Comment: @vlaz How much would you rate my answers

Answer (score 0):

You could delete the property by using [`Reflect.deleteProperty`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Reflect/deleteProperty).

```js
var array = [{ name: "vv", age: "12", id: "123" }, { name: "v2", age: "13", id: "123" }, { name: "v3", age: "123", id: "124" }];

array.forEach(o => Reflect.deleteProperty(o, 'age'));

console.log(array);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this :**

```js
var jsonString = '[{"name":"vv","age":"12","id":"123"},{"name":"v2","age":"13","id":"123"},{"name":"v3","age":"123","id":"124"}]';

var jsonObj = JSON.parse(jsonString);

jsonObj.map(obj => {
  delete obj.age;
  return obj;
});

console.log(jsonObj);
```